# Using a Python script to concatenate URL + CSV data, then send a request to each version of the concatenated URL

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I wish to read a list of strings from 3 separate columns in a CSV file and concatenate the string with a URL, then send requests to the URL for each individual URL created through iterating through the CSV, the response from the URL will be a JSON which I plan to store in a new CSV file. So far I am able to read the data from the CSV but I think the issue is the concatenation of the URL to the column values. I can read the data from the CSV file and when I print(URL) it prints the URL successfully concatenated with the last row of my CSV but add a ".0" to the end. I cannot figure this out ):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json
from urllib import response


#read cvs file select the columns you need with 'usecols='
df = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/top_10_nft.csv', usecols=['chain','contract_address' ,'token_id'],delimiter=',')
contract_address = df['contract_address']
chain = df['chain']
token_id = df['token_id']

df.dropna(subset=['chain','contract_address' ,'token_id'])


data = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
     chain = row['chain']
     contract_address = row['contract_address']
     token_id = row['token_id']

url = f"https://api.opensea.io/v2/chain/{chain}/contract/{contract_address}/nfts/{token_id}"
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "X-API-KEY": "d4f769dccc874df19ced833c630b3ea0"
}

print(url)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#data.append(response.json())




# drop all null rows using dropna(subset=[column-name])
df.dropna(subset=['chain','contract_address','token_id'])





#concatinate URL


#nft_data = data['nft']


#print(response)
```

I hope I am going about this the right way. This is the result of printing "URL" the "34.0" at the end should just be "34" which is why i think I'm getting 500 error. Additionally, this URL shown in the screenshot is the result of a successful concatenation with the last row of the CSV data I'm reading in, is this okay? or is it skipping the rows of data above?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me using `csv` module.  ignore the `StringIO` bits and use the proper path to your *file.csv*

```py
from pprint import pp
import io
import concurrent.futures
import csv
import requests

FILE = """\
chain,contract_address,token_id
ethereum,0x8a90CAb2b38dba80c64b7734e58Ee1dB38B8992e,34
"""

timeout = 10
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': 'd4f769dccc874df19ced833c630b3ea0'
})

def worker(url, timeout=timeout):
    return session.get(url=url, timeout=timeout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # with open(FILE, newline='') as file:
    with io.StringIO(FILE, newline='') as file:
        urls = []
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            chain = row.get('chain')
            contract_address = row.get('contract_address')
            token_id = row.get('token_id')
            if all((chain, contract_address, token_id)):
                url = f'https://api.opensea.io/v2/chain/{chain}/contract/{contract_address}/nfts/{token_id}'
                urls.append(url)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        data = []
        futures = [pool.submit(worker, url) for url in urls]
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                response = future.result().json()
                data.append(response)
            except Exception as E:
                print(future.result(), url)
                print(type(E), E)

    for i in data: pp(i)
```

Comment: Hi Richard, quick question what is the variable FILE doing here?

 FILE = """\
chain,contract_address,token_id
ethereum,0x8a90CAb2b38dba80c64b7734e58Ee1dB38B8992e,34
"""
also you're suggesting I put the PATH to the file with the data here?

with io.StringIO(----->FILE<------, newline='') as file:

Comment: it is a string that is used to simulate the contents of a file.  
[StringIO Module in Python](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-paPYvdKAAxUDhe4BHVPDDFsQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fstringio-module-in-python%2F&usg=AOvVaw32mt1OZCK-h9RgI8EXBFex&opi=89978449) is an in-memory file-like object. This object can be used as input or output to the most function that would expect a standard file object.

Comment: no, FILE should be the path to your *file.csv* and use `with open(FILE...` and delete the `with io.StringIO(FILE...` line.

Comment: Got it! also 

what is this part of the code doing btw?

 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        data = []
        futures = [pool.submit(worker, url) for url in urls]
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                response = future.result().json()
                data.append(response)
            except Exception as E:
                print(future.result(), url)
                print(type(E), E)

    for i in data: pp(i)

Comment: Hi Richard, I noticed that the JSON is not being sent a new CSV file. What can I add to the code to accomplish this?